# How to use google indoor maps for indoor navigation

Tags: android, ios, google-maps, indoor-positioning-system, google-indoor-maps

our customer want's to have a *BLE (ibeacon or eddystone)* based indoor navigation / wayfinding (*turn-by-turn* navigation) in his shopping mall app (*ios/ android*).

he has already uploaded and created all floor plans/ indoor maps here:
http://www.google.com/maps/about/partners/indoormaps/

the idea is, to equip the mall floors with *BLE* devices and use them as *non-gps-trigger* for a *indoor position* which will be shown on the already uploaded floor plans/ indoor maps.

Or should i equip the floors with *BLE devices* and use the *Google Maps Floor Plan Marker* once again ?
Because *google* says:

> To further improve location information, Google periodically sends in-field operators into some stores to run scans. Operators use the Floor Plan Marker app to scan for publicly available information, like Wi-Fi, GPS, Bluetooth BLE, and cell tower signals.

Source: https://support.google.com/maps/answer/2803784?co=GENIE.Platform%3DiOS&hl=en

How can this be work ?

Comment: Never though that google will do that for you...

Comment: how do you mean ? is there a solution already exists ? in case yes, which one ?

Comment: Exactly the opposite, i always thought that you need to do it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I think the gps in google map is not accurate.

Estimote indoor SDK would be the way you can try.

Reference: http://developer.estimote.com/indoor/

P.S. Estimote is one type of beacon that can emit BLE

Comment: Estimote indoor SDK is only available for iOS.